# How to fix crackling sound in PulseAudio

Tags: sound, audio

I have been experiencing a crackling sound after enabling the PulseAudio Equalizer.

Comment: Already had load-module module-udev-detect in my default.pa. Added tsched=0 but crackling still present if the volume is >100%

Answer (score 3):

*(the following answer was provided by OP himself, but was originally included in the question body.)*

> Searching for a solution I found one within the Arch wiki and I wanted to share it with everyone. This typically affects machines with Intel sound chips.
>
> ```
> sudo -i scratch-text-editor /etc/pulse/default.pa
> ```
>
> Add line below to end of file, then save
>
> ```
> load-module module-udev-detect tsched=0
> ```
>
> Then type in terminal:
>
> ```
> pulseaudio -k
> pulseaudio --start
> ```
>
> I've added this to the [elC - elementary Combobulator](https://gist.github.com/PretzelJones/05ff9ae2af0570b86aaebc385c341428) project as well.

Comment: your code is miswritten
it should be SCRATCH instead of sratch.

Comment: That's why it's always suggested you type commands manually rather than copy paste ;)